# Selecting a Particular class inside another class and getting the inner html from a DOM using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am stuck with this thing.May be an immature question.I dont know,I am pretty new to programming.I want to get a particular elements inner html from DOM of the page.The problem is the page is so complex it has so many classes subclasses href,span and all kind of things.**Here is what it looks like from the POINT OF VIEW OF MY REQUIRED CLASS**(there are a lot of other class and id's but this is the navigation to my required class,I skipped others.)

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class=
  <span style=
     <iframe class=
       #document
       <html id=
          <body class=
            <div class=
              <div id=
               <div id=
              <div class=
                 <div class=
                  <span id=
                   <a class=
                    <div class= "required class"
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <span>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </body>
           </html>
          </iframe>
         </span>
        </div>
       </body>
<html>
```

Is there anyway to get the particular element using `getelementbyID,getelementsbyClassName` or any javascript property ?
Is this the correct one ?

```
document.getElementById('main').getElementsByClassName('test');
```

IF so how ?
I am not getting any output so I was was wondering this method is right or not..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a solution, but for that, you will need to post the code correctly ;). Use [Ctrl+K] shortcut after selecting entire code block to make it readable.

Comment: If you add an id attribute to the element you want to select, you can then access it using getElementByID()..

Comment: Could you suggest which particular class you needs to select.

Comment: No this site is designed by me,I trying something like crawling.@johncarter

Comment: @TahirAhmed Sorry I am new to this website.I did something else and there was no preview to check what I did

Comment: @stanze <div class= "required class"

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but are you trying to access content that sits *within* an iframe?

Comment: @TahirAhmed,yes offcourse,its in an iframe,its an embedded code from another site talking more clearly.

Comment: @NeoStan Take a look at the answer I have posted. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `iframe` is loaded from the same domain and you want to access the contents within this `iframe`, you will have to do something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('required class');
```

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/fw3ffrjj/) for example which loads `fiddle.jshell.net` in its **iframe** and applies a **red** color to the first editor found. Code of which is as belows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror-scroll')[0].style.backgroundColor="red";
```

Comment: Yeah this is almost what I was looking for,but since the iframe uses that page itself,its kind of got complex to my newbie brain in programming.I will figure it out anyway...need some time.Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the inner HTML of a DOM element then here is what you can do,

First access the element by it's id and use `innerHTML` to get the HTML content inside of it as,

```
var x = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML;
alert(x);
```

You are not getting proper output because you are not referencing the object and not accessing it's HTML content with `innerHTML`

**EDIT:** To access elements by class names you can use below script,

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
for(var i=0;i<x.length;;i++){
    alert(x[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: getting inner html is my secondary issue.I dont know how to select that particulat element.Its a class element by the way..